# Problem passing variables through html, javascript and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jeditable

I'm using JEditable and trying to populate a select based on a variable.  I need a way to pass a variable from my page back through the JQuery to dynamically create the select.

JQuery:

```
$(".dblclick_district").editable('miscfreqs.php?mode=save_edit&module=miscfreqs&type=district',
{
    type: 'select',
    loadurl: 'tools.php?mode=get_districts_json',
    submit: 'OK',
    event: 'dblclick'
});
```

The HTML that I use is generated by PHP:

```
<div class="dblclick_province" id="freq_id">Province</div>
<div class="dblclick_district" id="freq_id">District</div>
```

I'd like to be able to somehow pass the value of province through the dblclick event of District, since the Districts available depend on which Province is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing two elements on the same page cannot have same id.
In your case both `div` are having same `id` ie freq_id so it should be changed.

You can have html as below -

```
<div class="dblclick_province" id="province_id">Province</div>
<div class="dblclick_district" id="district_id">District</div>
```

Then write the below code in your js file.
It uses jquery's [dbclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#district_id').dblclick(function() {
    var province_value = $('#province_id').html();
   // write you code here in which you want to process province value.
  });
});
```